# Proof Help: Row rank = Column rank, approach using coordinate maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**This question *may* be off topic, as it pertains not necessarily to the *best* proof for a theorem, neither does it ask for a *different* proof, but rather it asks for a proof in a particular approach, which may be unreasonable, but nonetheless I choose to post this. The reason is, I think this line of thinking *can* lead to the proof, but that's a subjective feeling. As a result, if you're down voting, or close-voting, please let me know in the comments *why* you don't like this question**

I am stuck trying to prove the mentioned theorem, and my primary goal is to not use rank-nullity theorem, as I feel like it can be proven without that. If possible, help me complete this proof: let $$A= \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}&A_{12}&\dots&A_{1n}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&\dots&A_{2n}\\\vdots\\A_{m1}&A_{m2}&\dots&A_{mn} \end{bmatrix}_{m \times n}$$ $$=\begin{bmatrix}[\alpha_1],[\alpha_2],\cdots,[\alpha_n] \end{bmatrix}_{m \times n}$$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}^m$ are the column vectors of $A$. A sequence of row operations on $A$ amounts to a pre multiplication with an invertible matrix $P \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times m}(\mathbb{F})$.

**Claim**: $A$ and $PA$ have the same column rank.

**proof(?)**: $[PA]_{ij}=\sum_{x=1}^m P_{ix}A_{xj}$$\implies$
$$[PA]=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{xn}\\\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{xn}\\\vdots \\\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{xn} \end{bmatrix}$$
A vector $\omega$ from the *span* of the column vectors of $PA$ is given by:

$$[PA][x]=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{1x}A_{xn}\\\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{2x}A_{xn}\\\vdots \\\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{x1}&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{x2}&\dots&\sum_{x=1}^m P_{mx}A_{xn} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}^n$

$$[[PA][x]]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n [PA]_{ik}x_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{t=1}^m P_{it}A_{tk}x_k=\sum_{t=1}^m P_{it}(\sum_{k=1}^n A_{tk}x_k)=\sum_{t=1}^m P_{it}[Ax]_{t} $$ The expression for $[PA][x]=\omega$ can be written as $$\tag{1} \omega=[P_1]\sum_{j=1}^n A_{1j}x_j+[P_2]\sum_{j=1}^n A_{2j}x_j \dots +[P_m]\sum_{j=1}^n A_{mj}x_j$$ where $[P_i]$ is the $i$-th column vector of the invertible matrix $P$. Since $P$ is invertible, we know from experience that its column vectors(written in standard basis) form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^m$. Hence, in coordinate form, $(1)$ can be rewritten as: $$[\omega]_{P\text {basis}}=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{j=1}^n A_{1j}x_j\\\sum_{j=1}^n A_{2j}x_j\\ \vdots \\\sum_{j=1}^n A_{mj}x_j \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2 \dots + A_{1n}x_n\\A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2 \dots + A_{2n}x_n\\ \vdots \\A_{m1}x_1+A_{m2}x_2 \dots + A_{mn}x_n \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}[\alpha_1]x_1+[\alpha_2]x_2 \dots + [\alpha_n]x_n\end{bmatrix}$$

**Theorem**: Let $V$ be an $m$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{F}$ and let $\mathscr{B}_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$ be two ordered bases of $V$. Then there exists a unique, invertible matrix $P$ such that for any vector $\gamma$ in $V$,$$P[\gamma]_{\mathscr{B}_2}=[\gamma]_{\mathscr{B}_1}$$ P's column vectors are given by writing the basis $\mathscr{B}_2$ in terms of the 1st basis.

In our proof, we set $\mathscr{B}_2$ to be the column vectors of our initial $P$, and $\mathscr{B}_1$ as standard. Then, naturally, we have:
$$P[\omega]_{P \text{basis}}=P\begin{bmatrix}[\alpha_1]x_1+[\alpha_2]x_2 \dots + [\alpha_n]x_n\end{bmatrix}=[\omega]_{\text{standard}}$$

I'm not able to think farther from here..

PS: For some background context: I am reading Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra, 2nd ed. and I know this theorem is treated in chapter 3 with the use of transformations, null spaces, rank nullity and so on, but I have a strong feeling this theorem can be proved within the bounds of the 1st 2 chapters (ie. Linear equations (matrices) and Vector spaces)

Comment: Both of the intermediate statements that you have proved have quicker proofs. If you note the general fact that $\text{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{\text{rank}(A),\text{rank}(B)\}$, then you have
$$
\text{rank}(A) \leq \text{rank}(PA) \leq \text{rank}(P^{-1}PA) = \text{rank}(A).
$$
For your second theorem, it suffices to note that the transformation that takes $\gamma$ to $[\gamma]_{\mathscr B}$ is linear and invertible.

Comment: My preferred proof of the equivalence of row-rank and column-rank uses a [rank-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) and the fact that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, see [this section of a relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proof_using_linear_combinations) for a similar approach. Perhaps that gives you a satisfying way to move forward here. Whatever it is that you do, I would suggest that you should probably make use of a relevant property of the transpose.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the ideas, i have proved the theorem, although embarassingly, I had to abandon my old approach. truth be told it was kind of unnecessarily long and inefficent